# GCD fraction code error and not printing out correct answers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to get the GCD of the function and print out the final output after dividing the input.

```
print('Welcome to Fraction Simplifier')
print('Type "exit" to quit.')

def getInput():

    x = (input('Enter Fraction (Int/Int):\n'))
    if x!='exit':
        x = (input('Enter Fraction (Int/Int):\n'))
    new_list = x.split('/') #['10', '/', '2']

    return new_list


def gcd(a, b):

    if int(b) == 1 or int(b) == 0:
        print('Simplified Fraction')
        print(a)
    else:
        print('Simplified Fraction')
        gcd(int(b),int(a % b)) #a =b b = b = a % b
        print(int(a/b),'/',int(a%b))

if __name__== "__main__":

    x = getInput()
    a = int(x[0])
    b = int(x[1])
    gcd(a,b)
```

My issue with this is, when I try to print it out it is getting random numbers, and I have no idea where they are coming from. Any ideas of what may have gone wrong?

Once this works it is supposed to do this: 30/4 will be solved to 15/2 (Final Output)

Comment: In getInput() you are overriding your first input x with the new input. To keep the first one store them in two different values or a tuple/list.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `print()` calls in the `else` part of `gcd()`. Because this is a recursive function you only want one print call. As far as [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) is correct, the recursion should only stop when b==0.